# Create a dummy variable indicating whether a value is observed before

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a huge dataset and wanted to create a binary dummy variable indicating whether a value is observed before. Here is the sample data set.

```
data.frame(
  id = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
  time = rep(seq(1:3),3),
  item = c(11,12,13,11,11,13,22,11,22))
```

From the dataset, here is the desired column,

```
observed_b4 = c(NA,0,0,NA,1,0,NA,0,1)
```

For each group, I want to have information about whether `item` is observed before or not. I can do it with `for-loop` but the data size is too big to do.

Comment: Maybe see `duplicated`?

Answer (score 1):

Using *duplicated*:

*base*:

```
cbind(x, flag = as.integer(duplicated(paste(x$id, x$item))))
#   id time item flag
# 1  A    1   11    0
# 2  A    2   12    0
# 3  A    3   13    0
# 4  B    1   11    0
# 5  B    2   11    1
# 6  B    3   13    0
# 7  C    1   22    0
# 8  C    2   11    0
# 9  C    3   22    1
```

or *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(flag = as.integer(duplicated(item)))
## A tibble: 9 x 4
## Groups:   id [3]
#  id     time  item  flag
#  <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
#1 A         1    11     0
#2 A         2    12     0
#3 A         3    13     0
#4 B         1    11     0
#5 B         2    11     1
#6 B         3    13     0
#7 C         1    22     0
#8 C         2    11     0
#9 C         3    22     1
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with base R that uses: `ave` and `duplicated`.

`ave` allows you to apply a function over `df$item` for each group made by `df$id`. `duplicated` checks whether an item was already shown. `ave` returns automatically a numeric vector (the name class of the input vector).

```
df$observed_b4 <- ave(df$item, df$id, FUN = duplicated)
df
#>   id time item observed_b4
#> 1  A    1   11           0
#> 2  A    2   12           0
#> 3  A    3   13           0
#> 4  B    1   11           0
#> 5  B    2   11           1
#> 6  B    3   13           0
#> 7  C    1   22           0
#> 8  C    2   11           0
#> 9  C    3   22           1
```

---

However, to get **exactly** what you're looking for, you can use this:

```
df$observed_b4 <- ave(df$item, df$id, FUN = function(x) replace(duplicated(x),1,NA))
df
#>   id time item observed_b4
#> 1  A    1   11          NA
#> 2  A    2   12           0
#> 3  A    3   13           0
#> 4  B    1   11          NA
#> 5  B    2   11           1
#> 6  B    3   13           0
#> 7  C    1   22          NA
#> 8  C    2   11           0
#> 9  C    3   22           1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could group by 'id', 'item', create a logical vector with `row_number()` and coerce it to binary (`+`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id, item) %>%
     mutate(flag = +(row_number() != 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id, item [7]
#  id     time  item  flag
#  <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
#1 A         1    11     0
#2 A         2    12     0
#3 A         3    13     0
#4 B         1    11     0
#5 B         2    11     1
#6 B         3    13     0
#7 C         1    22     0
#8 C         2    11     0
#9 C         3    22     1
```